# Jest Mocking Class.Class.Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

How do I mock a class.class.function?

For example:
I have an instantiated class:

```
const twitterClient = new TwitterClient({
  apiKey: process.env.TWITTER_API_KEY_ID,
  apiSecret: process.env.TWITTER_API_SECRET_KEY,
  accessToken: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  accessTokenSecret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
});
```

I need to mock this function call

```
await twitterClient.media.mediaUploadStatus()
```

media is a class called by Twitterclient

I've tried doing this:

```
jest.mock('twitter-api-client', () => {
  return {
    TwitterClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      media: {
        mediaUploadStatus: jest.fn(() => ({})),
      },
    })),
  };
});
```

Here is the TwitterClient code:

```
declare class TwitterClient {
    private basicsClient;
    private accountsAndUsersClient;
    private tweetsClient;
    private directMessagesClient;
    private mediaClient;
    private trendsClient;
    private geoClient;
    private metricsClient;
    private transport;
    /**
     * Provide Twitter API Credentials and options
     * @param options
     */
    constructor(options: IClientOptions);
    get basics(): BasicsClient;
    get accountsAndUsers(): AccountsAndUsersClient;
    get tweets(): TweetsClient;
    get directMessages(): DirectMessagesClient;
    get media(): MediaClient;
    get trends(): TrendsClient;
    get geo(): GeoClient;
    get metrics(): MetricsClient;
}
export { TwitterClient };
```

And MediaClient:

```
declare class MediaClient {
mediaUploadStatus(parameters: MediaUploadStatusParams): Promise<MediaUploadStatus>;
    /**
     * The FINALIZE command should be called after the entire media file is uploaded using APPEND commands. If and (only if) the response of the FINALIZE command contains a processing_info field, it may also be necessary to use a STATUS command and wait for it to return success before proceeding to Tweet creation.
     *
     * @link https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-finalize
     * @param parameters
     */
}
```

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks it seems it lacks the `./`, you could also try a spy: `spyOn(TwitterClient.prototype.media.mediaUploadStatus, TwitterClient.prototype.media.mediaUploadStatus.name)` https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mediaUploadStatus' of undefined. I don't understand why its not finding media when I try spyOn? And it doesn't have the ./ cause 'twitter-api-client' is an npm package, not another file I wrote.